# Contract transaction couldn't be found after 50 blocks in Kovan

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, testnets, kovan

When deploying contracts on the ledger I faced with issue

> Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful
>   transactions manually. Error: Contract transaction couldn't be found
>   after 50 blocks

Quick research brings insight it might be caused by not synchronised state between node and the ledger.  Just waiting for right block.

Kovan console doesn't represent such data. How I can see what blocks right now processing and where is my tx in this pipeline?  Do you have any other thoughts?

Comment: I get this today. I checked the Kovan block explorer + locally, I was synced. I was able to deploy just a few minutes before.

Comment: @Gleichmut, What tools are you using? How do you connect to Kovan?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are connected to a node that has a problem and it is not synchronizing with the rest of nodes. To check the last block and network status you can visit [kovan.etherscan.io](https://kovan.etherscan.io/). You can there compare your local node blocks with Kovan blocks...

However, to get rid of this hassle, I recommend using Truffle and connect to kovan through [infura.io](http://infura.io) (it is from ConsenSys).
To do this you can use the following inside your `truffle.js`:

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");

var mnemonic = "candy maple cake sugar pudding cream honey rich smooth crumble sweet treat";

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    //Other networks' configuration...
    kovan: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://kovan.infura.io/[your_infura_token]")
      },
      network_id: 3,
      gas: 47000000,
      gasPrice: 10000000000
    }

    //Other networks' configuration...
  }
}
```

To get a token from infura.io you just need to register at their site; And it is free. After registration they will send you your token by email.